# One large toolbar in split view on iPad

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I am currently working on porting my Android tablet application (http://tinyurl.com/cnejnjs
) over to iOS. My application basically consists of a list view on the left and a detail view on the right. Xcode has a built in view controller (Split View Controller) which seems to do a lot of the work for you.

I would like to make the navigation bar on the one large toolbar so I can add multiple controls to filter the list view (see Android app for all the filters that the user can apply). In interface builder with the split view controller I can not find a way to add the toolbar to the top. It seems I could style the two navigation bars, to make them look like one but when the user puts the device into portrait mode the left part of the navigation bar will be removed.

I have managed to build a view similar to what I want from scratch in IB but this would mean I don't get all the split view stuff for free and may make it harder to make an iPhone view if I later decide too.

[image: IB custom view]

Which way do you think would be best to approach this type of design?

Comment: one approach might be to hide the navigation bars that come with the splitViewController, and then embed the whole thing in a view in which you create the nav bar that you have on the top.  you can then probably get most of the splitViewController behavior that you want by tying the buttons from your own bar to actions that simulate the splitViewController actions … and if/when you go to iPhone, you can just rely on the normal navigation controller and not hide it and put the buttons that you want there … though you would only get a button on the left and a button on the right if you do that.

Comment: According to the Apple docs the UISplitViewController can only be assigned to your app's root view controller property.  It cannot be embedded as a subview to another view.  One solution would be to create your own custom view controller container class, but as you note, you'd have to duplicate a lot of the functionality that the UISplitViewController class already provides for you.

Comment: Also note that you can prevent the left (master) table view controller in the split view controller from disappearing in portrait view by implementing the `splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:` method

Comment: I tried to embed the splitview in another view but had no joy doing that. At the moment I just have one large view with everything in. Not very particle at all. How would I go about splitting it up, I can't seem to put two view controllers inside another in IB.